# get private key for Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, itext, smartcard, private-key

I am trying to retrieve the private key from the Keychain for digital signing later.

With the code below, I can get to all my certificates in the smart card and local drive, but not the private keys.  I have many private key and certificate pairs in the smart card.

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("KeychainStore", "Apple");

keyStore.load(null, "-".toCharArray());

Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();

while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    String alias = aliases.nextElement();

    if (keyStore.isKeyEntry(alias)) {
        try {
            PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, "-".toCharArray());
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("    Key failed to load ("+e.getMessage()+")");
        }

        Certificate certificate = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);

        String subject = "";

        if ((certificate != null) && (certificate instanceof X509Certificate)) {
            subject =((X509Certificate)certificate).getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve the private key a specific certificate? `getKey()` always returns null except for one system private key.